# Configure Database in Google App Engine

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, jpa

I've read and understand google APi for CRUD operation in data. But where is the data? Because normally to configure the persistance layer, we need to specify where the data is in the XML file. For ex: name of the database, login and password,...
But how to do that with GWT? And how to physically create a real database in the google app engin?
Thanks

Comment: What google API are you referring to? Do you mean the google app engine?

Comment: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/jpa/overview.html

Comment: what does GWT have to do with a database ? its a GUI layer.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend reading this help page from google: http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html

But essentially you create your entity and persist and they'll create the tables for you. its pretty nifty give it a shot.

Comment: +1 for reading the google documentation.  It's long and confusing, and in some places incomplete, but it's a great way to get started.

Comment: I know how to use XML or annotation to configure the mapping. But when we develop in localhost, we actually don't have the connection to the datastore, in that case we can not test the system?

Answer (score 0):

Google documentation is a reference for all of us. But is it a good start to grasp basic concepts? Not so much (especially when its examples use JDO or JPA)...

The following links should definitely help:

[Fundamental Concepts of the Datastore](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/wiki/Concepts) (I do not endorse Objectify here - just this introductory page; but do give consideration to APIs such as Objectify and Twig-Persist after you get comfortable with basic concepts).

[Life of a Datastore Write](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/life_of_write.html)

[Transaction Isolation in App Engine](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/transaction_isolation.html)

and the rest of the [Mastering the datastore series](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/datastore/overview.html) in your spare time ;-).

[Introduction to low-level API](http://ikaisays.com/2010/06/03/introduction-to-working-with-app-engine%E2%80%99s-low-level-datastore-api/)

Some critique: [Google App Engine's Datastore Falters Under Demand](http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/197970/google_app_engines_datastore_falters_under_demand.html)